# How can I change the text size of bookmarks in Files / Nautilus?

Tags: 18.04, nautilus, themes, gtk, bookmarks

I have a bunch of bookmarks in Files/Nautilus and would like to reduce the text size of/space taken up by the entries in the left hand bookmarks column, so that I don't have to scroll to access those at the bottom of the list (I use a trackball mouse that has no scroll wheel).

[image: screenshot of Files/Nautilus]

Is this possible? If so, how?

Comment: what is the gtk theme you are using?

Comment: I am using Adwaita-dark - one of the built in themes in 18.04.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ubuntu 18.04
Radiance Theme..

add the below content under the last line in `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/apps/nautilus.css` file. change the font-size value 12px to your preferred size.

```
/* for side bar reduced text size */

.nautilus-window placessidebar.sidebar row.sidebar-row {
    font-size:12px; }

button.sidebar-button {
    min-width: 2px;
    min-height: 2px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}
```

open other file `/usr/share/themes/Radiance/gtk-3.20/gtk-widgets.css` and find the below content in around line number 2201.

```
placessidebar.sidebar row.sidebar-row {
    color: shade(@places_sidebar_fg_color, 0.9);
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-height: 12px;
    border:none;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

here i have already changed min-height to 12px to match with font-size as we already declared in `nautilus.css` file above.

save the files and reboot to see the change.

Radiance Theme after configuration:
[image]

Note: Different GTK themes have different type of arrangements like everything is configured in a single file or some themes like Radiance theme have separate apps folder and nautilus.css file in it. you may have to do trail and errors with the key lines like `.nautilus-window placessidebar.sidebar row.sidebar-row` and other fields too as mentioned in above codes.

other configured theme.
[image]

Edit: for Adwaita Dark Theme, you can add the same content under the line
`@import url("resource:///org/gtk/libgtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained-dark.css");` in `/usr/share/themes/Adwaita-dark/gtk-3.0/gtk.css` file

```
@import url("resource:///org/gtk/libgtk/theme/Adwaita/gtk-contained-dark.css");

/* for side bar reduced text size */

.nautilus-window placessidebar.sidebar row.sidebar-row {
    font-size:12px; }

button.sidebar-button {
    min-width: 2px;
    min-height: 2px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    padding: 0;
}

placessidebar.sidebar row.sidebar-row {
    color: shade(@places_sidebar_fg_color, 0.9);
    background-image: none;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: top left;
    background-color: transparent;
    min-height: 12px;
    border:none;
    text-shadow: none;
}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for this. Unfortunately it looks like the theme I'm using (Adwaita-dark) doesn't follow the same structure. I can't find where to make these changes.

Comment: Brilliant - thank you!! It turns out that a better solution for my needs was to reduce the space between the entries in the list, but your code snippet included what I needed for that - took me about 10 minutes of trial and error to find it but now I have lots of space for new bookmarks without the need to scroll. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

1. Use Tweaks (gnome-tweaks).

   Go to Tweaks > Fonts > Interface and reduced the font size.

   [image: Tweaks-1]

   [image: Tweaks-2]
2. You can remove the entries that you have made.
   Right click on the entry and click on Remove.

   [image: Files]

Comment: I believe 4n3wv is not asking how to remove them but  how to reduce font size of that bookmarks only.